# R Copying from console to word while preserving formatting

Tags: r, formatting

So for a homework assignment I need to paste my console to the word document, but the console looses all formatting and spacing and gets messy in my word document. Pictures attached below. Assistance would be much appreciated! I tried copying to notepad\excel and then to word too, didn't help.

[Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cozi.png)

[Word Document after pasting console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RfPb.png)

Comment: Format your text in Word to use a fixed-width font -- Consolas, Lucida Console, or Courier New for example.

Comment: Alternatively, use `Rmarkdown` with file output specified to "word_document" in the header.

Comment: why not simply screenshot it?

Answer (score 0):

Manually copying code output anywhere is most likely not the best approach, it leads to spacebar & delete key abuse. For such tasks there are many tools available. The most powerful among them is **Rmarkdown**.

1. Open a new Rmarkdown document, and change its output to Word

[image]

2. Port your code to the new file.
3. **knit** the document, and find your formatted code open in a word document.

[image]

4. Spice up your Rmarkdown knowledge, and learn about its features! Presentation slides, websites, multi-lingual code support, reproducible dynamic reports and much more is possible.

Some resources to kickstart your rmarkdown adventure:

- [Rmarkdown: The definitive Guide (Yihui Xie)](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/): in-depth explanation of what Rmarkdown is, and how it works.
- [Rmarkdown cookbook, chapter 8 (Yihui Xie)](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/word.html) for more details on how to work with word document outputs.
- [A handy cheatsheet](https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/rmarkdown-cheatsheet.pdf) to get familiar with its syntax